# Map-Reduce on `system.profile` collection

Tags: mongodb, profiler

I have a simple collection `posts` with a few documents in it. I have set the profiling level to 2 allowing for profiling information to be collected into another collection `system.profile`. My goal is to use a *mapReduce* operation to collect information from the `command` entry grouped via various actors using this simple query:

```javascript
db.system.profile.mapReduce(
    function()
    {
        emit( this.appName, this.command  );
    },
    function( key, values ) 
    {
        return JSON.stringify(values);
    },
    {
        query: {},
        out  : "command_maps"
    }
)
```

However, trying this in the REPL yields the following error

```
2021-05-10T22:09:33.494+0800 E QUERY    [js] Error: map reduce failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "rename failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"error with source namespace: cannot write to 'test.tmp.mr.system.profile_22'\", code: 20, codeName: \"IllegalOperation\" }",
    "code" : 10076,
    "codeName" : "Location10076"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.mapReduce@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1145:1
@(shell):1:1
```

I suspect mongo is trying to *temporarily* write into the `system.profile` collection and fails due to it being readonly in a sense. Is there any way to execute this successfully ?

Unfortunately the documents are too large to add here but basically its sort of like this:

DOCUMENT

```json
{ 
   "appName": "actor1",     
   "command": {"find": {},"ns" : "test.post""} 
}, 
{  "appName": "actor2", 
   "command": { "find": {},"ns" : "test.comments"} 
}
{
   "appName": "actor1",
   "command": { "insert": {},}
}
```

OUTPUT

```json
{  appName: "actor1": command_maps: '[{command: "find"}, {command:"query"} ...]' } 
{    appName: "actor2": command_maps: '[{command: "find"}...]' }
```

Version: MongoDB shell version v4.4.5

PS     : mapReduce is working properly on regular collections

Comment: Why do you try to mapreduce the `system.profile` collection?  Use an aggregation pipeline as recommended in documentation.

Comment: Yeah, its quite an expensive operation but basically by doing aggregation we would end up with a cartesian product and we can't deterministically know the fields which the `command ` subdocument will have. However in this situation its kind of weird that mongo is trying to rewrite into the same collection during the query.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired result? I don't think an aggregation pipeline will cause problems. mapReduce does not seem to be "state of the art" anymore.

Comment: main thing to note is the command document can vary in contents

Comment: Please put additional information into the question instead of a comment.

Comment: The input data is invalid JSON and the output data does not match the input (e.g. there is no "query" element in the input). Provide valid samples if you like to get a valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems special `readWrite` privileges are needed to execute mapReduce on `system.profile` collection. So I got the query to work eventually after checking through:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/